# wso2is-km upgrade from 5.7 to 5.10

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am upgrading wso2is-km  from 5.7 to 5.10. I am following document. 
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/migrating-to-5100/

But I am getting below error. Can you please provide link for db script which is required for migration?

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO IDN_OIDC_SCOPE_CLAIM_MAPPING (SCOPE_ID, EXTERNAL_CLAIM_ID) SELECT 6,IDN_CLAIM.ID FROM IDN_CL
AIM LEFT JOIN IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT ON IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT.ID = IDN_CLAIM.DIALECT_ID WHERE CLAIM_URI='sub' AND IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT.DIALECT_URI='http://wso2.org/oidc/cla
im' AND IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT.TENANT_ID=-1234 was aborted: ERROR: insert or update on table "idn_oidc_scope_claim_mapping" violates foreign key constraint "idn_oidc
_scope_claim_mapping_scope_id_fkey"
  Detail: Key (scope_id)=(6) is not present in table "idn_oidc_scope".  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:148)

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "uuid" does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "sp_app.id".
  Position: 310


Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "image_url" does not exist
  Position: 302
```

Detailed error:

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while executing :   DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS OIDC_SCOPE_DATA_MIGRATE_FUNCTION
        at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator.executeSQL(SchemaMigrator.java:303)
        at org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.service.SchemaMigrator.executeSQLScript(SchemaMigrator.java:234)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input
  Position: 59

Comment: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest//install-and-setup/upgrading-wso2-is-as-key-manager/upgrading-from-is-km-570-to-5100/ followed the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the provided migration client in the doc, it executes the relevant DB scripts and you don't have to execute any DB scripts manually again.

Can you please recheck whether you followed the steps correctly in the doc?

Please note the following in the doc for PostgreSQL.

"During the migration, "uuid-ossp" extension is created in the database. In order to create this extension, the database user should have the 'Superuser' permission. If the user is not already a superuser, assign the permission before starting the migration.

`ALTER USER <user> WITH SUPERUSER;`"

Comment: Thanks for update.I followed steps correctly. Still same issue. Same steps are working for 5.7 to 5.9. is there any difference in 5.7 to 5.10. Also I found image_url column is no there in migration db script.Can you please help on this issue.